# What are the consequences of a faster algorithm for $CIRCUIT$-$SAT$?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, ds.algorithms, circuit-complexity, sat, big-list

1. What is the best algorithm known for $CIRCUIT$-$SAT$ in $n$ variables and $m$ gates?
2. What is the consequence if there is an $\alpha\in(0,1)$ such that $CIRCUIT$-$SAT$ in $n$ variables and $m$ gates can be solved in $2^{(n-n^\alpha)}poly(nm)$ time?

Comment: For 1, this is not better than SAT with $n$ variables and $m$ clauses so I would say no better than bruteforcing. For 2, $O(n-n^\alpha)=O(n)$ thus it is completely trivial. Just bruteforce... Now, if you mean $2^{o(n)}$ then it will violate SETH.

Comment: I was thinking $\frac{2^{O(n)}}{superpoly}$.

Comment: $2^n/superpoly$, otherwise $2^{2n}/2^n$ would work...

Comment: (2) is known to imply circuit lower bounds against NQP due to [Cody Murray and Ryan Williams' STOC 2018 paper](https://people.csail.mit.edu/rrw/easy-witness-nqp.pdf). Ryan has a really nice talk on these kinds of results with recordings [here](https://simons.berkeley.edu/talks/lower-bounds-algorithm-design-i) and [here](https://simons.berkeley.edu/talks/clone-lower-bounds-algorithm-design-ii).

Comment: @RobertAndrews Seems like a good answer!

Comment: Neat question!  I've been looking for others to work with on consequences of faster algorithms for circuit SAT if anyone is interested.  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure how to answer (1), but (2) is known to imply circuit lower bounds against NQP (non-deterministic quasi-polynomial time). This is from [Cody Murray and Ryan Williams' STOC 2018 paper](https://people.csail.mit.edu/rrw/easy-witness-nqp.pdf).

In fact, they show that these lower bounds follow from faster algorithms for what they call Gap Circuit Unsatisfiability: given a circuit $C$ on $n$ variables and the promise that either (a) $C$ is unsatisfiable, or (b) $C$ has at least $2^n/4$ satisfying assignments, determine which of (a) and (b) is the case. This problem is easily solved with randomness, so this hypothesis is perhaps more likely than a faster algorithm for Circuit Satisfiability.

Ryan has a very nice talk on this thread of work; a recording in two parts is available [here](https://simons.berkeley.edu/talks/lower-bounds-algorithm-design-i) and [here](https://simons.berkeley.edu/talks/clone-lower-bounds-algorithm-design-ii).

Comment: So faster Gap Circuit Unsatisfiability follows from faster CIRCUITSAT?

Comment: Yes. You can solve Gap Circuit Unsatisfiability by checking if the input circuit is satisfiable.